# Datalist search innerHTML rather than value?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am attempting to create a way to search for a user by typing their name in a text field, then changing a list below. The easiest way I saw to do this way by using a `datalist` but it seems that a datalist's search go off the `value` and not the `html` of the element.

Is it possible to change the search from looking at the `value` to the `html`?

Context:

```
<input class="mrg-btm" type="text" placeholder="Search..." list="users" />
  <datalist id="users" name="formSec" required>
    <?php
    $get = $users->prepare("SELECT userID,userFirst,userLast FROM users");
    $get->execute();
    $get->store_result();
    $get->bind_result($userID,$userFirst,$userLast);
    while($get->fetch()) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $userID; ?>"><?php echo $userFirst. ' ' .$userLast; ?></option>
    <?php
    };
    $get->close();
    ?>
  </datalist>
```

As you can see, I am assigning the `userID` to the `value` and not the name, I would like to be able to search for the name of the `user` without having to put it as the `value`, is this possible?

Comment: so if this is possible will your `option` be like this instead: `<option><?= $userID ?></option>`

Comment: So you want to have the username as another attribute?

Comment: And another thing is, that it is not supported on 23% of the computers (browsers the users use) and is buggy in IE/Edge. [http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist).
So if it's not just for playing around with it I would use another solution.

Comment: @szoszk, no I would like the `value` as `userID` but I want to display and be able to search from the `userFirst & userLast`

Answer (score 0):

You can make up attributes in HTML5 by prefixing them with `data-`. So in your case you need to do it like this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $userID; ?>" data-userFirst="<?php echo $userFirst ?>" data-userLast="<?php echo $userLast ?>"><?php echo $userFirst. ' ' .$userLast; ?></option>
```

Now you can use javascript to get the vlues of the attributes.